# Getting time value from timepicker - android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-widget

There seems to be a lot of varied information on the net on how exactly to take the time entered on a timepicker by a user and do something with it. I want to take the user input time, save it to a variable and write to an SQLite Database. I can't figure out how to convert the TimePicker values into a variable that can be passed to the SQL database where it will be stored in a timestamp field. I'm open to alternative suggestions if this is not necessarily the best way to go about it. Thanks!

This is my code so far:

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" >

    <TimePicker android:id="@+id/tpTimeStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnUpdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;

public class AddModule extends Activity {

    TimePicker tp1;
    Button bUpdate;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.add_module);
        bUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);

        bUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
        tp1 = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.tpTimeStart);
        Time timestart = tp1.getCurrentHour(), tp1.getCurrentMinute();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's so many ways to do this, but it all depends on what else is going to use it
SQLite seems to use HH:MM:SS.SSS

You can use GregorianCalendar and SimpleDateFormat together, or you should do it the hard way and make the string manually.

Comment: do you think it would be better if I use a java Stringbuilder? Make the hour a string and the minute a string, create one string from the 2 and write it to the SQL db? I'm writing a reminder app so I want the app to display a message or sound an alarm tone 1 hour before the time the user puts in

Comment: For building strings, stringbuilder is recommended. The reason is because String operations in Java fire off a lot of gc calls